# Debugger sets enormous initial values eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I have a tiny code on C++. When I try to debug it, I see the initial values of the variables are huge. Is it normal or I have any problems with C++ / Eclipse? Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int c = 5;
int a = c++;
int b = ++c;
cout << a << b << c;
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer you've gotten is pretty spot on. Accepting Romens answer is good for everyone seaking an answer to the question you had.

Answer (score 6):

It is normal.

Your breakpoint is set *before* `int c = 5;` is executed. At that point in time  `a`, `b`, and `c` are uninitialized. The debugger is showing the value in the memory allocated for those variables but it will be overwritten as the next few lines are executed.